# How to use Facebook Login in a modal view in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios4

I'm trying to modify the demo that comes with the Facebook iOS SDK.
I need the login button appears in a second modal view.

When I click on the login button, it opens Facebook App and authorization is sought, then returns to my app but fbDidLogin is not fired.

I have followed all the steps from here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.

Here is the code i'm using. Please help me to find out what i'm missing.

I'm using Xcode 4.1 and iOS SDK 4.3

**myAppAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "loginView.h"
#import "firstView.h"

@class firstView;

@interface myAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    firstView* controller;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet firstView *firstViewViewController;

@end
```

**myAppAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "firstView.h"
#import "loginView.h"

@synthesize window;

@synthesize firstViewViewController = _ firstViewViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    controller = [[firstView alloc] init];
    firstView *firstView = [[firstView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[controller fb] handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [_firstViewViewController release];
    [controller release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**firstView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface firstView : UIViewController

-(IBAction)openLoginView:(id)sender;

@end
```

**firstView.m**

```
#import "loginView.h"

@implementation firstView

-(IBAction)openLoginView:(id)sender{
    loginView *loginView = [[loginView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**loginView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface loginView : UIViewController<FBRequestDelegate,
FBDialogDelegate,
FBSessionDelegate>{
    NSArray* _permissions;
    Facebook* _fb;
}
@property(readonly) Facebook *fb;
-(IBAction)fbButtonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

**loginView.m**

```
#import "loginView.h"

static NSString* kAppId = @"260718013943480";

@implementation loginView

@synthesize fb = _fb;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (!kAppId) {
        NSLog(@"missing app id!");
        exit(1);
        return nil;
    }
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _fb = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)login {
    [_fb authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
}

- (IBAction)fbButtonClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"login button clicked");
    [self login];
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"logged in");
}

/**
 * Called when the user canceled the authorization dialog.
 */
-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
    NSLog(@"did not login");
}

/**
 * Called when the request logout has succeeded.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogout {
    NSLog(@"logedout");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, how does this even compile?

```
@synthesize firstViewViewController = _ firstViewViewController;
```

You don't have _firstViewController declared anywhere.
Secondly, I think you are mixing views and view controllers.
Finally, your view controller that handles FB authorization (loginView) should implement

> FBRequestDelegate,FBDialogDelegate,FBSessionDelegate

So your loginView.h should look something like:

> @interface loginView : UIViewController <
>   FBRequestDelegate,FBDialogDelegate,FBSessionDelegate>{

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I think in the iOS SDK 4.3 you don't have to declare the viewController, just declare the property and synthesize it.

What do you mean with "I think you are mixing views and view controllers"?

About the "FBRequestDelegate,FBDialogDelegate,FBSessionDelegate", that was a copy/paste error, i have already  edited my question with the code.

Comment: I just think it is weird that your view controller is called "loginView". Anyway, is your fbButtonClick method fired? You manage to succesfully log in? And you never reach fbDidNotLogin function?

Comment: You are right about the view controller called "loginView", it should be called "loginViewController" my mistake.
The "fbButtonClick" method is fired, and then is fired the "login" method. Then, it switch to the Facebook App and ask for authorization, i authorize and when is back to my app, the "fbDidLogi"n method is not fired and neither "fbDidNotLogin". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly is your button that fires `fbButtonClick` method? Did you forget to paste that too?
Secondly, please check the settings of your Facebook application. Under "Mobile" section, you'll see "Apple iOS" part. There, you need to enter your iOS Bundle ID. Something like: http://db.tt/qr6Q8II. Finally, make sure you have fb app id in your .plist file (URL types > Item 0 > URL Scheme).

Comment: Thanks for your help again!
The button that fires the `fbButtonClick` is in a nib file called loginView.xib, here i have a `UIButton` connected to the `fbButtonClick` method. Also, i have entered my iOS Bundle ID into my Facebook Application settings page and finally i have the fb app id in my .plist file and still not working. But i have changed `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];` to `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];` in the Facebook.m file, and now it works but is not using the Facebook App auth mode (single sign-on flow)

Comment: Here is the Xcode project with some changes in the ViewController names: [MyApp.zip](http://cl.ly/0R0H0K2v050G2l0u0p3J)

Comment: did you manage to solve it? I took a look at your code, and indedd, with `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]` it is working as expected. otherwise, I'm clueless.

Comment: Try this: in your app delegate, add:
`-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url { return [[loginView fb] handleOpenURL:url]; }`